# How to use WordNet thesaurus in Whoosh

Tags: python, wordnet, whoosh

I'm new to Whoosh and I want to expand search queries using synonyms, similar to what Elasticsearch does with its Synonym Token Filters. The most similar thing I could find is the `Thesaurus` class from `whoosh.lang.wordnet`. I've already downloaded and copied my `wn_s.pl` file, but now I'm stuck on how to get it to work with Whoosh. I couldn't find any `Thesaurus` or `whoosh.lang.wordnet` usage anywhere in the Whoosh source code nor any helpful Google results about it. Not even the [Whoosh docs](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has more information about it except for help with the module's functions and the `Thesaurus` class itself.

So how do I load and use the WordNet database in Whoosh? I'm using Whoosh 2.7.4 on Python 3.6.

Comment: did u find solution for this problem? if yes, can you please share it here, i am searching for the same